# Unable to use OAUTH2 Django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I'm following this tutorial https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html, and unfortunately I'm stuck in this part

"Point your browser to //localhost:8000/o/applications/ and add an Application instance"

unfortunately when I go to that URL, I get the following error and redirected to

"localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/o/applications/"

and page not found error, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guide doesn't mention it but you need an authenticated session before you can access that page.  Add the following steps:

Create a user:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Start up the django server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Get a validated session by logging into the admin page with the admin account that you just created:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin
```

Then navigate to the page the guide references:

```
http://localhost:8000/o/applications/
```

Comment: Totally true, I was stuck on the project for weeks, should at least be mentioned... Thanks a lot